# Layout looking the same across all devices using RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, adt, mobile-devices, screens

I'm using API 10.

I want to make my layout looking the same across all devices. I can achieve that by using `LinearLayout` with `weights`. It works perfectly. As seen on the image below, this is exactly what I want to achieve and it works perfectly:

[image]

But the problems that occur are two:

- 1)I get a warning of low performance because of nested weights.
- 2)I can't make animations out of bounds of the parent LinearLayout,
  as shown in the image below:

[image]

So, I decided to make my layout with `RelativeLayout`. But the major problem is that I can't get the same layout across  all devices, like LinearLayout and usage of weights. I spent two days searching for a solution and reading the ADT documentation. According to the documentation I have to make my `ImageViews` scaled to a factor of `3:4:6:8:12`, to match the `ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xdpi/xxdpi`. So I did: I created the corresponding @drawble folders, re-sized my buttons as the document says, and placed them inside the matching folders. The result is this:

[image]

This is a mess, it is totally unacceptable, for two reasons:

- 1) Screens may be of a certain density, for example hdpi, but they
  differ from device to device of a certain screen size.
- 2) When I use the dp units  relative to an element, for example: from
  top of parent, the value I provide differs from screen size to screen
  size. It is not by percentage like in LinearLayout.

**So, where do I go from here?** I concluded from my reasearch, that the only(**or not?**) solution is to make different layouts for different densities AND screen sizes. Like `res/layout-mdpi-large/my_layout.xml` and so on. But **how** do I calculate the dp for sizes and distances from relative components, based on the screen sizes? Do I have to resort to this list? Are these all the devices?:

[image]

Any tips, best practices, guides for the workflow, anything?

Comment: They screwed this up by not allowing us to use percentages, use JAVA code to set layout params.